# OpenCover Isn't Passing Arguments to NUnit

Tags: .net, nunit, opencover

I just grabbed NUnit, NUnit Runners, and OpenCover from Nuget.  The NUnit parts are running great, both in GUI and console mode.  But in PowerShell I can't seem to get OpenCover to work properly.  Following various examples of usage, I ended up with this command:

```
.\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"..\NUnit.Runners.2.6.1\tools\nunit-console.exe" -targetargs:"/noshadow C:\Path\To\Tests.dll" -filter:+[*]* -output:coverage.xml
```

I see the opening copyright info from NUnit, but then NUnit tells me:

> fatal error: no inputs specified

Followed, of course, by standard help output describing the flags and whatnot.  Then, naturally, OpenCover also displays an error indicating that nothing matched the filter and there are no results.

So I tried running NUnit directly:

```
..\NUnit.Runners.2.6.1\tools\nunit-console.exe /noshadow C:\Path\To\Tests.dll
```

And it runs fine.  Tests pass, everything's happy.  Thinking that maybe the documentation and examples are outdated, I tried combining the `targetargs` directly into the invocation:

```
.\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"..\NUnit.Runners.2.6.1\tools\nunit-console.exe /noshadow C:\Path\To\Tests.dll" -filter:+[*]* -output:coverage.xml
```

But the error output is still the same.

Am I missing something in the proper usage of OpenCover?  How can I get it to properly interact with the NUnit console runner?

Comment: Can you try without the "/noshadow" parameter?

Comment: @HenryAloni: Interesting. Trying without `/noshadow` on the non-`targetargs` attempt makes no difference. However, if I go back to splitting out the `targetargs` and remove `/noshadow` from that attempt then NUnit successfully runs the tests. OpenCover, however, still reports that "no assemblies that matched the supplied filter were instrumented, this could be due to missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter." There are, however, PDB files in the output bin where I point it for the tests DLL.

Comment: Looks like opencover takes wrong parameters. Can you try to put each param in it's own qoutes :OpenCover.Console.exe "-target:..\NUnit.Runners.2.6.1\tools\nunit-console.exe" -output:.\test.xml "-targetargs:MyApp.Merchant.nunit /noshadow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be to do with setting the current working directory first?

I also have my filter argument in quotes, e.g. `-filter:"+[*]*"`

Might be worth ruling these out at least...

Comment: Interesting, it looks like the working directory is probably the culprit.  If I go out to some random directory and use absolute paths for everything (in my example I was using relative paths for the OpenCover executable and the NUnit executable) then I get the same results.  However, navigating to the compiled output folder for the tests assembly and again using absolute paths for everything seems to work.  So when I automate this I _should_ be able to just use `Set-Location` as the first line in the script.  Hopefully.